# Banach contraction theorem solution verification

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I have to find the limit of sequence

$ x_0= 2019 $

$ x_n= \frac{3}{5}x_{n-1} + 2 \sqrt{x_{n-1}} +3$

for $n=1,2,3,...$

using Banach theorem.

I assumed that $f(x)=\frac{3}{5}x+2 \sqrt x+3$

First I want to prove that f(x) is a contraction mapping:

**EDIT:**
As spotted in the comment my proof for the inequality was incorect so know I am stuck at:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{3}{5}x+2 \sqrt x+3 - \frac{3}{5}y-2 \sqrt y-3|=|\frac{3}{5}(x-y)+2(\sqrt x -\sqrt y)|$

I thought about using the inequality $|\sqrt x- \sqrt y|< \sqrt{|x-y|}$ but I have no idea how to proceed from here.

The next step would be that if f(x) is a contraction mapping then the limit would be a positive solution to

$\frac{3}{5}x+2 \sqrt x+3=x$

After some calculation I get that $x=\frac{5}{2}+\frac{5 \sqrt55}{2}$ and that is our limit.
Is this a right way to do solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure about the inequality? It says that $ |a + b | < |a|$ even though $a,b$ have the same sign.

Comment: To clarify, I'm saying that your inequality is wrong. E.g. take $ x = 1, y = 0 $.

Comment: Yes you are right, I don't know how I could not see it. I've edited my question, but know I have no idea how to show that it is a contraction.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. $ \sqrt{x}$ isn't a contraction at $x=0$.

Comment: So how can I find the limit of this sequence using Banach theorem?

Comment: Try to study the variation of you function, then from $x_0=2019$ you find a  minimum at $x=(\frac{18}{5})^2$ so I'm studiying the regularity of the sequences

Answer (score 1):

So first we have

$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=\frac{3}{5}x_n+2\sqrt{x_n}+3 \ \ \ (0)$$

We have $$ f'(x)=\frac{3}{5}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$

So $$f(x) \geq \dfrac{48}{5} \ \ \text{when} \ x\geq (\dfrac{3}{5})^2 \ \ \ (2)$$

---

Further  more we study $f(x)-x$ in order to know the monotony.

$$ f'(x)-1=\dfrac{-2}{5}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \leq 0$$ for $x >0 \ \ \ (2)$

---

Now by iteration we show :

- $\forall n \geq 0, x_n>0 $ using (0)
- $\forall n \geq 0, x_{n+1}-x_n\leq 0$ using (3)

So because $x_n$ is decreasing and lower-bounded using (2) it converges.

You know that limits is a fix point of $f$ .

Hence your result.